# When animating a 2d object `Transform.Translate()` stops working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I'm developing an enemy AI in a 2D Game that I'm working on. This enemy swims and I wanted to make a "floating effect" animation for the enemy, so I made an animation where the Y Axis of the game object bounces up and down.

[image]

I Use `transform.Translate()` to move the enemies in the game and it worked just fine until I made this animation. But, when the animation is playing, the enemy can't move in any direction.

```
public virtual void Move(float speed)
{
    if (canMove)
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(speed, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could control the characters y.position in script, so you don't have the conflict between your script and unity's animation system. Conceptually i think it's a better idea to keep locomotion confined to one system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a keyframe in **any** state of your animator for a certain property the animator will always overrule any changes done in a script because the animation updates are all done [after `Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). You could try to either move your code to `LateUpdate`.

Or in your specific case you do not want the `x` component of your position keyframed at all. Simply remove all the keyframes for the `x` (and `z`) component(s) of the position from the animations so **only** `y` has keyframes. This should solve your problem.

---

Alternatively use your movement script on a GameObject on a higher level in the hierachy as your `Animator` - meaning add a new GameObject, make the animated object a child of it and place your movement script instead on that parant object.